# contentInsetを設定するとscrollToItem(..)でスクロール移動できないセルが発生する現象を回避するには？

Tags: swift, ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

`collectionView`で指定セルまでスクロールさせたいのですが、`contentInset`を設定すると `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`メソッドではスクロール移動できないセルが発生して困っております。

問題を分かりやすくするために、以下のような横スクロールのコレクションビューを作成してみました。数字を表示するだけのセルを隙間なく並べたコレクションビューです。（下図にあるセルの境界線は`UICollectionViewCell`カスタムサブクラスのサブビュー(`UIView`)によるものです。）

「SCROLL」ボタンをタップすると`UITextField`に入力した数字と同じ`item`まで自動スクロールします。指定セルが中心に表示されるよう、左右に１セル幅分だけ`contentInset`を設定しています。

```
let cellWidth: CGFloat = 50
collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: cellWidth, bottom: 0, right: cellWidth)
```

セル３つ分の幅のコレクションビューなのですが、セル１を指定した場合のみ思うように動作してくれません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【 問題点 】

- セル０の時にセル１を指定すると、スクロールしない
- セル２以上の時にセル1を指定すると、スクロールし、中央がセル０になる

上の例では、「SCROLL」ボタンをタップしたタイミングで、`scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`を呼び出しています。

```
@objc private func handleScrollButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

  if let text = textField.text, let number = Int(text) {
    selectedNumberLabel.text = text

    // テキストフィールドで指定された番号のセルまでスクロール
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: number, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  }
  textField.resignFirstResponder()
  textField.text = nil
}
```

対策として、セル１のみで発生するので、セル１の場合のみ`UIView.animate(..)`を用い `contentOffset.x`をアニメーションさせて他のスクロールと同様に見せかける方法を試したのですが、

```
  if number == 1 {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
      self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = 0
    })
  }
  else {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: number, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  }
```

離れたセルからセル１にスクロール移動する場合に、間のセルが自動補完されないため、数字が消えたり`collectionView`の背景色が見えたりして、スムーズなスクロールに見えません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`UICollectionView`で`contentInset`を設定した場合、すべてのセルへ問題なくスクロール移動するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

上の例でいうセル１へのより良いスクロール方法がありましたら、教えていただけませんでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試してみたところ、同様の現象を確認できました。

また、contentInsetのleftを１セル分よりも多く取ると2以降のインデックスでも同様に発生し、
leftとrightを異なる値にするとすべてのインデックスで中央に揃わなくなる、
などいろいろ起こるようです。

水平スクロールモードのUICollectionViewのバグだと思われますが、
とりあえず回避するなら、

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
  self.collectionView.contentOffset.x = 0
})
```

ではなく、 [setContentOffset(_:,animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset?language=swift) を使うとよいと思います。

Comment: setContentOffset(_:animated:)の存在をすっかり見逃しておりました

Comment: おすすめ通りに実装したところ、おかげさまでスムーズなスクロールが実現できました。ありがとうございます！他に手段のあるバグで良かったです。